# PropertyChangedEventHandler is null even property is change

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I have a data grid and one main checkbox. When I check changed in the main checkbox, this will affect all checkbox that inside data grid; I just do it programmatically.

[image: data grid]

My so-called `ViewModel`:

```cs
foreach (TimeSheetModel value in TimeSheetList.Intersect(selectedlist))
{

    if (!chkmain.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault())
    {
        value.IsApproved = false;

    }
    else                   
    {
        value.IsApproved = true;                                
    }
}
```

This is my `TimeSheetModel`:

```cs
public class TimeSheetModel:BaseModel, ICloneable
{
    bool _IsApproved;
    public bool IsApproved
    {
        get
        {
            return _IsApproved;
        }
        set
        {               

            if (_IsApproved != value)
            {
                _IsApproved = value;                           
                RaisePropertyChange("IsApproved");                   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `BaseModel`:

```cs
public class BaseModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{            
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChange(string prop)
    {
        try
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
                IsUpdated=true
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }            
    }
}
```

This is my `xaml`:

```xml
<DataGridTemplateColumn Visibility="{Binding IsShowApprove,Source={x:Static c:TMSHelper.Current}}">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        Margin="-8">
                <TextBlock  Text="Approve"
                            Height="20"
                            Margin="5,3,0,0" />
                <CheckBox Margin="27,0,0,0"
                          x:Name="chkMainApproved"                        
                          Checked="chkApproved_Checked"
                          Unchecked="chkApproved_Checked">
                </CheckBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox BorderThickness="1"
                      Margin="27,0,0,0"
                      Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}},Path=Background}"
                      IsChecked="{Binding IsApproved,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"
                      KeyDown="DatePicker_KeyDown"
                      >
                <CheckBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroCheckBox}">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                                Value="True" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLock}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsLock}"
                                               Value="True" />                                                      
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                                        Value="False" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsNew}"
                                               Value="True" />
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding CanAdd}"
                                               Value="False" />
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                                        Value="False" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsNew}"
                                               Value="False" />
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding CanEdit}"
                                               Value="False" />
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                                        Value="False" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </CheckBox.Style>
            </CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

According to my understanding, if I change the `value.IsApproved=true` (inside ViewModel) this will raise the `IsApproved` property inside `TimeSheetModel` and go to `RaisePropertyChanged` method and go to `PropertyChanged` and `IsUpdated` property will be true.

My problem is My `propertyChanged` is sometimes null, sometimes has value. Even if `IsApproved` value was changed.

This is not happening in all checkbox.

Hope you will understand my question and pls let me know anything I can provide.

Comment: Can you show your xaml code?

Comment: @ManpritSinghSahota ,Pls check the update.

Comment: What does the output window say when you load the view and when you check the box? Any errors?

Comment: No error and when I check the main checkbox, it all checkboxes are checked because of its check by programmatically but IsUpdate property for some row are false even property change.

Comment: Move `IsUpdated=true` out of `if` statement, otherwise the `IsUpdated` only being modified if there are subscriber for `PropertyChanged`.

Comment: Can't move IsUpdated property to outside of if statement,becoz while initializing the form, all property will go to raisepropertychange and isupdate property will be always true even I am not anything change.