# PropertyChange is null when property change by programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I have a checkbox column in DataGrid and one main checkbox in DataGrid column. when I check the main checkbox, all of the selected checkboxes that inside in DataGrid will be check.

When I check the main checkbox, I check all of boolean property like that =>

```
foreach (TSModel value in TimeSheetList.Intersect(selectedlist))
            {

                if (!chkmain.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault())
                {
                    value.IsApproved = false;                     
                }
                else
                {
                    value.IsApproved = true;                      
                }
            }
```

My TSModel =>

```
public class TSModel:BaseModel, ICloneable
{

    bool _IsApproved;
    public bool IsApproved
    {
        get
        {
            return _IsApproved;
        }
        set
        {               

            if (_IsApproved != value)
            {
                _IsApproved = value;
                RaisePropertyChange("IsApproved");                   
            }
        }
    }

 }
```

My BaseModel =>

```
public class BaseModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChange(string prop)
    {
        try
        {               
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
                IsUpdated = true;
            }                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }            
    }
    bool _IsUpdated = false;
    public virtual bool IsUpdated
    {
        get
        {
            return _IsUpdated;
        }
        set
        {
            _IsUpdated = value;
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is if I check individual, This propertychanged is not null and IsUpdated property is true but If I check by Main checkbox and check change by Code, This propertychanged is null and IsUpdated is false.

Why my propertychanged is null when I check by code?

Update

- I saw another don't know the reason, I have 100 lines and I can see only 15 records and rest are shown by vertical scroll. So when I check change all checkbox but if I only see 1 to 15, this 1 to 15 only propertychanged value has value and rest are null.If i vision to 85 to 100,only 85 to 100 and 1 to 15 propertychanged value has value and rest are null.

Comment: Hi, Someone pls edit my question for code format. I don't know why I can't change my code to code format.there is no option in the body section.

Comment: Not an answer just a tip, but when calling `RaisePropertyChange` pass `nameof(...)` rather then `"..."`, this will prevent you from getting tripped up by a typo or if you were to change the property name etc...

Comment: This question seems to be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55918532/propertychangedeventhandler-is-null-even-property-is-change#comment98491893_55918532)

Answer (score 1):

This is expected since the items that you don't currently see, i.e. the lines between 16 and 100, are virtualized. There is no need to raise the `PropertyChanged` event for these as they are not visible on the screen anyway.

You should still set the property value of these objects though, but you shouldn't have to worry about the `PropertyChanged` event not being raised. The `RaisePropertyChange` method of your base class should not do anything else than raising the event:

```
public class BaseModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChange(string prop)
    {
        try
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    bool _IsUpdated = false;
    public virtual bool IsUpdated
    {
        get
        {
            return _IsUpdated;
        }
        set
        {
            _IsUpdated = value;
            RaisePropertyChange("IsUpdated");
        }
    }
}
```

You should set the `IsUpdated` property in the setter of `IsApproved`:

```
public bool IsApproved
{
    get
    {
        return _IsApproved;
    }
    set
    {

        if (_IsApproved != value)
        {
            _IsApproved = value;
            RaisePropertyChange("IsApproved");
            IsUpdated = true;
    }
}
```

The other option is to set the properties *before* the `null` check:

```
public void RaisePropertyChange(string prop)
{
    try
    {          
        IsUpdated = true;     
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }                
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }            
}
```

If you have bound the `CheckBox` correctly, it will get checked or unchecked based on the source property as soon as it becomes visible, i.e. when you scroll it into view.

You can read more about the concept of UI virtualization in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-controls).

Comment: Thanks, Its look like what now I am facing. But user won't be scroll down after check the main checkbox so how can I do that?

Comment: @Arkar: How can you do what? You don't need to bother about the `PropertyChanged` event being null for the virtualized items. There are no subscribers for an item that is not visible.

Comment: Even the items are not visible, the property should be changed. My requirement is like that and Now I fixed temporarily by matching two lists but I know that is not good for performance.

Comment: I have no idea how to fix that one and StackOverflow is the only one I can ask for help.thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't set the `IsUpdated` property in the `RaisePropertyChange` method. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks, I can't put `IsUpdate` in Set and if I put there, This `IsUpdated` will be always true. Because when I start to bind to list `IsApprove` will be false and some records are already true so will be going to set and IsUpdate will be true even there is no changing yet.

Comment: @Arkar: Makes no sense. Set `_IsApproved` instead of `IsApproved` initially. The method that raises the event should not set the property anyway.

Comment: I have other fields like `IsApprove` and IsUpdated is inside the `basemodel` .Every model that inside my project are use `basemodel` and I think moving IsUpdate to each of individual property will be impact to other stable things.Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Arkar: Set them before the null check then. See my edit.

Comment: I have one converter layer and that layer will convert object from database to my project model.At this layer i just convert like that` return (from f in dblist select new TSModel { IsApproved = f.IsApproved}).ToList();` This line will fire for `Set` property of IsApprove and IsUpdate will be true.

Comment: @Arkar: I don't know where you are going with this. I believe your question has been answered and there is an easy fix to your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but If I move 'IsUpdate' to outside of Null Checking Condition, this will be always true even I do not update the property yet. So I would like to fire the PropertyChanged property even filed is not seeing.

Comment: You are wrong. The property has already been updated by the time you call the method. Otherwise it makes no sense to call the method in the first place. Raising an event and updating a property are two different things.

Comment: Thanks @mm8. when we set the value of the property, it will go to set right? When we go to set, it will raise the `RaisePropertyChange`, right?

Comment: @Arkar: As already mentioned, the event won't be raised for the virtualized items. You shouldn't rely on it being raised.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your information. Programmatically update value is not also raise the event?

Comment: Setting the property doesn't raise the event. Why would you then define the `RaisePropertyChange` method at all?